# Gstreamer: how convert image/jpeg stream to video and send on RTSP?

Tags: stream, video-streaming, gstreamer, vlc, rtsp

I'm trying to stream webcam video to a VLC player using gstreamer 1.0.
Im use Logitech c270 webcam:

```
v4l2-ctl --list-formats
    ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
    Index       : 0
    Type        : Video Capture
    Pixel Format: 'YUYV'
    Name        : YUYV 4:2:2
    Index       : 1
    Type        : Video Capture
    Pixel Format: 'MJPG' (compressed)
    Name        : Motion-JPEG
```

gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src have [formats](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-v4l2src.html) `image/jpeg` and `video/x-raw, format=YUY2`
First I tried `video/x-raw, format=YUY2`, because it is more like a video, but there was no result (maybe it is very different from YUYV).
Then i tried `image/jpeg` and it worked!
Current command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video0 \
! 'image/jpeg,width=1280,height=720,framerate=30/1' \
! multipartmux \
! tcpserversink host=192.168.1.11 port=5000
```

Now Im open VLC: `tcp://192.168.1.11:5000` and see video.
But this `image/jpeg` and I think that this has a bad effect on network speed.
How can I convert this signal into video and broadcast it via RTSP to open at `rtsp://192.168.1.11:5000`?